jenkins is appending vcs tags to the artifactory file name
I'm setting up a new Jenkins system - ours is more than 4yo
I installed the addons and configured them based on the old system, created a maven project, with the same settings as on the old one, and trying to build it
The build fails because Jenkins is trying to publish artifacts to the self-hosted Artifactory OSS, but it fails since the file names have vcs tags appended to the filename
The error is
The requested URL /artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/<company name here>/<project name here>/2.5.24-SNAPSHOT/<project name here>-2.5.24-SNAPSHOT.jar;vcs.revision=9d1e9881e4bb41a7430301485b81b29aeef7ffb2;build.timestamp=1727297896823;build.name=<job name here>;build.number=567;vcs.branch=origin/master;vcs.url=https://bitbucket.org/<company name here>/<project name here> was not found on this server.
the old system deploys artifacts without vcs tags
the old system is Jenkins 2.263.4, Artifactory plugin 3.6.2
the new one is Jenkins 2.462.2, Artifactory plugin 4.0.8
how do i get rid of these tags being appended?
